Traversal of Binary Tree in Order traversal and start "Reverse Order" if node has no children Javascript
Given a tree, return the level order traversal of its nodes' values. (i.e., from left to left, level by level). Once, node has not children go for parent where it has unvisited children.
Sample data:-
    [
    {
        "id": 15,
        "parentId": -1,
        "isVisited": false,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "parentId": 15,
                "isVisited": false,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "parentId": 16,
                        "isVisited": false,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 12,
                                "parentId": 14,
                                "isVisited": false,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 13,
                                        "parentId": 12,
                                        "isVisited": false,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 21,
                                                "parentId": 13,
                                                "isVisited": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 20,
                                                "parentId": 13,
                                                "isVisited": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "parentId": 14,
                                "isVisited": false,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 1,
                                        "parentId": 3,
                                        "isVisited": false,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 18,
                                                "parentId": 1,
                                                "isVisited": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 11,
                                                "parentId": 1,
                                                "isVisited": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "parentId": 14,
                                "isVisited": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 100,
                "parentId": 15,
                "isVisited": false
            }
        ]
    }
]

Expected output:-
15, 16, 14, 12, 13, 21, 13, 20, 13, 12, 14, 3, 1, 18, 1, 11, 1, 3, 14, 2, 14, 16, 15, 100

handleTree function used to traverse the tree from top to bottom considering only the left nodes. Once left node is finished it will look for the other nodes towards it's right and once all children completed move to the top and check the other childs.
While tracing backward the tree only keep the main nodes.
const handleTree = (tree, path = [], visited = new Set() ) => {
        let result = [];
        let count = 0;
        let visitTree = tree
        if( tree && tree.length > 0 ){
            const tree2 = (tree) => {
                if (tree) {
                    
                    tree.forEach((t, i) => {
                        count += 1;
                        let { children, id, parentId, index, ...rest } = t
                        result.push({ ...t, id, parentId, isVisited: true, sid: count });
                        tree = updateIsVisited( tree, id, parentId )
                        path?.push( t.id );
                        if (t.children) {
                            tree2(t.children.sort( ( a: any, b: any ) => b.order - a.order ) );
                        } else {
                            
                            tree = updateIsVisited( tree, id, parentId )
                            path.pop();
                            const res = returnReverseNodesForTraversel( [...path], tree, t.id );
                            // Here data is not coming correctly
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return tree2(tree)
        }
    };

Update isVisted function
const updateIsVisited = ( nodesData, id ) => {

    return nodesData.map ( ( node: any ) => {
        const updatedNode = {
            ...node,
            isVisited: node.id === id ? true : node.isVisited,
            children: Array.isArray( node.children )
                        ? updateIsVisitedInNestedObjects( node.children, id )
                        : []
        }
        return updatedNode;
    })
}


It seems obvious that you're asking about a depth-first tree-traversal algorithm, but the question includes more than one example and no clear expectation regarding the sequence of node visit order… or the expected output. Can you [edit] the question to clarify?

@jsejcksn I added first data is for understanding purpose. Second one in which I am working using parent child r/s.

The question title mentions "binary tree" and "in order" traversal (with a reverse condition), but the question details conflict. The "expected output" describes a pre-order (NLR) traversal that repeats already-visited parent nodes which are encountered while discovering unvisited children… and the "sample data" in your question shows a structure that is not a binary tree: the node with id 14 has 3 children.

^ Are you attempting to implement an algorithm that works with generalized trees (nodes with 0+ children)? I'd like to help… I'm not willing to provide an answer until after the question is edited to reconcile the previously mentioned conflicts.

@jsejcksn I will update the question. It will take some time.

@jsejcksn I have updated the question with expected output.

^ @vikasdhiman In the latest edit, the expected output ends in 14, 16, 100, but shouldn't it be 14, 16, 15, 100?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What is your question?

The algorithm that you describe in the question is a variation on depth-first pre-order (NLR) traversal, which is indicated by the red dots in the image below:


Depth-first traversal (dotted path) of a binary tree (source: Wikipedia)

The difference in your description is that "intermediate" visited nodes are reiterated in the output — every node along the "visit path" is output until the last unvisited node.
Below is an example iterative implementation in TypeScript with comments explaining the procedure (note that the algorithm doesn't use the properties parentId or isVisited from the nodes in your example data — they aren't necessary):
Code in the TypeScript Playground
type Node<T> = Omit<T, "children"> & {
  readonly children?: Readonly<{
    length: number;
    toReversed(): Iterable<Node<T>>;
  }>;
};

function* traverse<T>(root: Node<T>): Iterable<Node<T>> {
  // Discovered nodes that must be evaluated
  const stack: Node<T>[] = [];

  // Map of: Child => Parent
  const parentMap = new Map<Node<T>, Node<T>>();

  // Memos of most recent node and leaf
  const previous: Partial<Record<"leaf" | "node", Node<T>>> = {};

  let node: Node<T> | undefined = root;

  while (node) {
    // Reiterate "intermediate" visited nodes: this is what differentiates
    // the ouput of this algorithm from typical preorder traversal
    const parent = parentMap.get(node);
    if (previous.node !== parent) {
      let intermediate = parentMap.get(previous.leaf!)!;
      while (intermediate !== parent) {
        yield intermediate;
        intermediate = parentMap.get(intermediate)!;
      }
      yield intermediate;
    }

    yield node;

    if (node.children?.length) {
      // Add children to stack in reverse order
      for (const child of node.children.toReversed()) {
        parentMap.set(child, node);
        stack.push(child);
      }
    } else previous.leaf = node;

    previous.node = node;
    node = stack.pop();
  }
}

The main difference from pre-order traversal in the algorithm above is the memoization of parent nodes, previous node, and previous leaf node — so that the "intermediate" visited nodes can be re-walked in reverse when descent begins again.
Finally, here's the compiled JavaScript from the TypeScript playground link, including a test using the data in your question so you can verify that it works:


"use strict";

function* traverse(root) {
  const stack = [];
  const parentMap = new Map();
  const previous = {};
  let node = root;
  while (node) {
    const parent = parentMap.get(node);
    if (previous.node !== parent) {
      let intermediate = parentMap.get(previous.leaf);
      while (intermediate !== parent) {
        yield intermediate;
        intermediate = parentMap.get(intermediate);
      }
      yield intermediate;
    }
    yield node;
    if (node.children?.length) {
      for (const child of node.children.toReversed()) {
        parentMap.set(child, node);
        stack.push(child);
      }
    } else {
      previous.leaf = node;
    }
    previous.node = node;
    node = stack.pop();
  }
}

function test() {
  console.clear();

  const dataFromQuestion = [
    {
      id: 15,
      parentId: -1,
      isVisited: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: 16,
          parentId: 15,
          isVisited: false,
          children: [
            {
              id: 14,
              parentId: 16,
              isVisited: false,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 12,
                  parentId: 14,
                  isVisited: false,
                  children: [
                    {
                      id: 13,
                      parentId: 12,
                      isVisited: false,
                      children: [
                        {
                          id: 21,
                          parentId: 13,
                          isVisited: false,
                        },
                        {
                          id: 20,
                          parentId: 13,
                          isVisited: false,
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  id: 3,
                  parentId: 14,
                  isVisited: false,
                  children: [
                    {
                      id: 1,
                      parentId: 3,
                      isVisited: false,
                      children: [
                        {
                          id: 18,
                          parentId: 1,
                          isVisited: false,
                        },
                        {
                          id: 11,
                          parentId: 1,
                          isVisited: false,
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  id: 2,
                  parentId: 14,
                  isVisited: false,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 100,
          parentId: 15,
          isVisited: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const rootNode = dataFromQuestion[0];
  const nodes = [...traverse(rootNode)];
  const actualIds = nodes.map(({ id }) => id);

  const expectedIds = [
    15,
    16,
    14,
    12,
    13,
    21,
    13,
    20,
    13,
    12,
    14,
    3,
    1,
    18,
    1,
    11,
    1,
    3,
    14,
    2,
    14,
    16,
    15,
    100,
  ];

  const equal = actualIds.length === expectedIds.length &&
    expectedIds.every((n, i) => n === actualIds[i]);

  console.log({ equal });
}

test();



